# firebase connect to database throwing invalid Database URL

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simply python app and I am trying to connect to Firebase, I downloaded my cert.json file and have a valid certificate that authenticates however when I try to create a reference to the database as according to the docs, it throws the following error:

> File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\db.py", line 69, in reference
> client = service.get_client(url)
> File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\db.py", line 798, in get_client
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Invalid database URL: "None". Database URL must be a non-empty URL string.

I have added my code below:

```py
import firebase_admin
import os
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import credentials

certfile = "firebase_cert.json"

credentials = credentials.Certificate(certfile)
database = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credentials)

ref = db.reference("/")
print(ref)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Firebase documentation for [initializing the Admin SDK in Python](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#python) shows, you will need to specify the URL for your document in your application code:

```
# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com' // 
})

ref = db.reference("/")
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!